# Cannot Call Class in Different Module (Dynamic Feature Module)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, modularization, dynamic-delivery

[image: Different Module Activity]

Hi, i've been trying to access DetailActivity in feature_profile module (Dynamic Feature Module) from MainActivity, but no luck. I've tried to access it with `Class.forName("com.dynamicfeature.feature.profile.DetailActivity")` and it throws an java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Am i missing something? has anyone overcome this? Would like to hear if you guys have a solution :) Thank you

Comment: Hi. Did you add the `feature_profile` module as `dependency` in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @namenotfound Hi, i did add it as dynamic feature in my App Build.gradle. Like this: dynamicFeatures = [":feature_profile"]. Then in my feature_profile i added  api project(':app')

Comment: I don't know what `dynamicFeatures` are but I guess you need to add dependency with `compile project(':your-module')`. Maybe take a look at [the gradle doc](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/)

Comment: turns out i need to put: apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' in my dynamic module :) thank for pointing it out @namenotfound

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i need to put `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` in my dynamic module build.gradle